# Failed to call IIS-hosted WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I'm trying to host my WCF service in IIS for internal testing.

I have no problem to add and consume the service in testing website 
inside the same PC as IIS. 
I also able to add the service into my testing website in another 
PC (LAN connection).

But the **problem** is that when I try to consume the service in 
testing website in another PC inside another PC (LAN connected), 
the service always keep saying that it failed to response.

I do hope anyone here who have experienced this kind of situation 
can share your precious experience. Thanks.

p.s: sorry for my broken english.

Here's my WCF web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="GeoIPService.ServiceMethodBehavior" name="GeoIPService.ServiceMethod">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="GeoIPService.IServiceMethod"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="GeoIPService.ServiceMethodBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Best regards,
Jason

Comment: Are you able to hit anything else hosted in IIS? Like, if you just put a static HTML page there? If that works, then can you open a web browser to the .aspx page, and have it show the default "landing page"? You should also post your WCF configuration in your question.

Comment: It didn't hit any errors in my current dev pc. The connection problem only happens when i try to access from LAN connected PC testing websites. Sorry, I just edited the post and put in the web config. U may have a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the format of the URL to your service that would help too as well as error you are getting.

For a quick and general connectivity issue I typically resort to Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). This tool shows the traffic between client and server. The next step would be turning on WCF diagnostics but before that make sure that you can: ping the target server, that you can navigate via URL to the service end point, and use fiddler for further connectivity debugging assistance.